# Is there a way to embed a page within another page?

Tags: structure, embeds, children, child

I'm not talking about embedding another template.

I'd like to embed all the child pages of a parent within the parent (for incredibly convoluted reasons).

I'm using Structure if that helps.

Using {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{structure:child_ids}" fixed_order="{structure:child_ids}"} I can get all of the child IDs that I need... I was hoping that something like {embed="{page_uri}"} would do the trick, but alas.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this will work out, recursively. Probably a huge performance hit and memory exhaustion leading to the parent page non-rendering at all. But, here is an outline of how you could do this (in pseudo EE code):

```
{!-- Parent template --}

Let's get our child ids.
{exp:channel:entries entry_id='{structure:child_ids}' fixed_order="{structure:child_ids}"}

    {embed='template_group/child_page_template' id='{child_id}'}

{/exp:channel:entries}

{!-- Child template normally used to show regular child page --}

Let's show our page, but load our channel loop depending on context.

{if embed:child_id}
    If passing an embed id...
    {exp:channel:entries id='{embed:child_id}' ... }
{if:else}
    If not, see if it's a normal structure page...
    {exp:channel:entries id='{structure:page_id}' ... }
{/if}

    Render it up!

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I guess another solution would be to write an add-on that just CURLS the page via AJAX and then returns it to your template. Or, what would be even easier (if this is an option for you), just use the `nav` tag to dump URLs into `iframes`: http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/navigation_examples/

If you could explain the context of this desired output and a slightly more specific example (like, COMPLETE child page renders, header+footer and all?), we can probably help more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way... but after a lot of trial and error; this seems to be working.

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{structure:child_ids}" fixed_order="{structure:child_ids}"}
  {exp:query sql="SELECT channel_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE entry_id = '{entry_id}'"}
    {exp:query sql="SELECT template_id FROM exp_structure_channels WHERE channel_id = '{channel_id}'"}    
      {exp:query sql="SELECT template_name FROM exp_templates WHERE template_id = '{template_id}'"}
        {embed="templates/{template_name}" id="{entry_id}"}
      {/exp:query}
    {/exp:query}
  {/exp:query}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```